# Getting a list of Windows event Logs VBA Access

Tags: xml, ms-access, vba

[image: Task Scheduler]

I am attempting to generate XML Tasks set up to trigger on events. Therefore I need the exact format of each log to inject into a generic XML template. Is there any way I can plug into the highlighted fields above to add them to a table in my database?

Comment: Why would you want to put fields from the event trigger into your database. Or do you mean to put the log and source fields of the event into your database? If the latter they are fields on the event log entry object.

Comment: The latter is correct. And could you elaborate how I would use the Event Log entry object from within Access/VBA so I could import them into a table?

Comment: you should be able to find lots of scripting examples of using WMI to read the event logs: that will be the easiest way from other (Com based) VB variants as well.

Comment: A bit of research into the object seems that it is easy to query actual logs, but I'm after the types of Logs / Sources. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394226(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, im not interested in the actual logs. Just the types of logs that can occur. So all the types of Logs, along with their sources

Comment: A list of logs and, it its Sources property the sources for that log, is available with the WMI [`Win32_NTEventlogFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394225.aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

After much research the closest answer I could find was to scan the registry folders for all the available logs.

For the fields I was after these were in the location:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\
```

From here on I used a loop in order to get the folder names. although to get all the results I will have to scan their subfolders (this is done by changing the path. Here is a code snippet below in case this problem is found by anyone else.

```
Function test()
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
Dim temp As Object
Dim strComputer As String
Dim rPath As String
Dim arrSubKeys()
Dim strAsk

strComputer = "."
Set temp = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

rPath = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Application"
temp.EnumKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, rPath, arrSubKeys
For Each strAsk In arrSubKeys
    Debug.Print strAsk
Next
End Function
```